# Calculate overall price using several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a linux 18.04. I was going to execute SQL code in VS Code to calculate how much money should pay my guests for staying. I have 3 tables - Reservation, Room and Invoice

```
DECLARE @day NUMERIC, @price NUMERIC, @total NUMERIC, @resID NUMERIC
SELECT @resID = resID FROM Reservation GROUP BY resID;
WHILE @resID <= 10
BEGIN
    SELECT @day = DATEDIFF(day, departure_date, arrival_date) FROM Reservation
    SELECT @price = price_per_night FROM Room
    SELECT @total = @day * @price;
    UPDATE Invoice SET overall_price = @total;
SET @resID = @resID+1
END

SELECT * FROM Invoice;
```

For example, if guest lives 2 days - (DATEDIFF(day, departure_date, arrival_date),
then it should calculate 2days * price_per_night(Room table)
put value in overall_price column in Invoice table

Comment: There is no clear question being asked and both sample data and expected output is missing

Comment: Start over - and this time start thinking about your code. Do NOT rely on default lengths, precision and scale when declaring variables or columns. "numeric" here means "numeric(18,0)". If you do indeed want to use that datatype (doubtful) then you should define it that way. And you will find the life is very messy. Not every guest at a hotel has a reservation. What do you do in that case? Sometimes price varies by day. Can I get a room for a single day (where departure and arrival are the same day)? That happens. There can be other charges as well. Food, bar, damage, missing items, etc.

Comment: Assuming you have some guest- you should only select and update rows for that particular guest - using a WHERE clause.  Also, an update statement can update multiple rows (multiple values for various rows) and you are using a declared variable (single value) which is not correct given the intent of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

So we see you have much to learn. All your existing code can be replaced with 2 statements - an update and a select. You think in terms of loops and single rows - something typical of traditional programming languages. In tsql, you need to think in terms of sets.

A basic pseudo-code example of what you should be doing is something like this:

```
update dbo.Invoice set overall_price = 
    (select price_per_night * datediff(day, arrival_date, departure_date) from ....)
where ... ;

select ... from dbo.Invoice order by ...;
```

That isn't working code. It needs to be adjusted in many ways. But notice that there must be a relationship between Invoice and Customer and Room. That is why DDL is requested and needed. And as I commented, you make many many assumptions that are simply not valid for real life. Perhaps this is a simple training exercise - something you should also mention when asking questions. Doing that avoids a lot of extra work describing potential pitfalls and complications and discussing complexity you don't need.

And some additional thoughts. The term "overall_price" is misleading. Your customer must pay a final or total amount. As I mentioned earlier, this is often more than just the charge for the room. Did you consider what happens when a customer uses multiple rooms? Is your goal to invoice for each room separately? And different rooms can have different rates. Did you consider taxes and other fees? Lastly, you really only want to update Invoices that are in some state indicating it has not been "completed". You don't want to update old invoices - especially paid ones. So there is still a lot of complexity here that you have yet to consider.

One code-specific comment. You have this:

```
SELECT @resID = resID FROM Reservation GROUP BY resID;
```

Think about what that does. Obviously you can and do expect it to produce many rows. So what value do you think it assigned to your variable? Does the language guarantee the value you expect? It does not. The value assigned will be one from the set produced but there is no guarantee that the lowest one will be assigned. This is a common and mistaken assumption. So how do you express your goal correctly in tsql?

```
set @resID = (select min(resID) from dbo.Reservation);
```

Notice some best practices you need to starting using. First, terminate your statements. Eventually it will be required. Next, use SET rather than SELECT to assign variables. There is a big difference. Finally, schema-qualify your tables. All these are best practices and you should spend some time learning them.

And one final thought. If you really need a loop, then use a cursor. And generally speaking, loops (and cursors) are something that you rarely need in effective, efficient tsql code. If you find yourself thinking a loop is needed in your code, it is time to take a step back to re-imagine your issue and the best path to a solution.